# How to add custom operator in DataStream API

Tags: apache-flink

I want to implement an operator that has two input streams and takes an item from each stream to process both simultaneously e.g. join. In addition, if one of both inputs does not have any data, the operator would block and wait for it.

If I have to do this, which classes are involved? A tutorial about it is much better. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give some more details?

Comment: I want to implement the operator that its input are two datastreams and take a item from each datastream to process simultaneously e.g. join. In addition, if one of two datastreams has no data, the other would wait for it. @Matthias J. Sax Look forward to your reply

Comment: That sounds like a use case for a [CoMapFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/apis/streaming_guide.html#co-operators). Did you check if it provides what you need?

Comment: Yeah! I had checked it and it didn't meet my requirement.@FabianHueske

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect two `DataStream` and apply a `TwoInputStreamOperator`. There is already a bunch of predefined operators. In your case, a `CoFlatMapFunction` would be a good choice:

```Java
DataStream input1 = ...
DataStream input2 = ...

input1.connect(input2).flatMap(new MyOwnCoFlatMapFunction());
```

Some more details here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html#co-operators

However, this operator cannot block as you wish it to do. Thus, you need to apply the following pattern: Each time you receive an input from left or right, you need to buffer the input if no input from the other side is available:

```Java
MyOwnCoFlatMapFunction implements CoFlatMapFunction {
    List<IN> leftInput = new LinkedList<IN>();
    List<IN> rightInput = new LinkedList<IN>();

    void flatMap1(IN1 value, Collector<OUT> out) throws Exception {
        if(rightInput.size() > 0) {
          IN right = rightInput.remove();
            // process left input (value) and right input (right) together
        } else {
             leftInput.add(value);
        }
    }

    // reverse pattern for flatMap2 here
}
```

However, you need to be aware that blocking is *dangerous* in stream processing. If your input stream have different date rates, this approach will not work(!), because the slower stream throttles the faster one resulting in back pressure for the faster one. I don't know your use case, but it seems to be something "wrong". Why can you not join on time?

Comment: As far as I know, join on time window just only process data in current window, which may cause data lose. For example, if time window trigger every 2s and the faster pipline send data with sequence ID x into window while the slower pipline haven't finish it.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow what you are saying. However, using a time window will **not** loose any data (I assume a tumbling window). Each time the window in triggered, your join function is called with two lists each containing all tuples belonging to the current window from the left and right input as parameters. Thus, the input list of the faster stream will contain more tuple than the slower stream. But no data will be lost.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't organize my words well. If one data called ID x from left is already in currrent window while the other data from right that must be joined with ID x hasn't been in current window. In this moment, the current window triggers process, which cause the data to miss each other. I also assume a tumbling window. Is it right?

Comment: You mean that input tuple x is "lost", because the second window might be empty? Yes, this could happen. Stream joins are inner joins. If you want to have every input tuple in the output stream, an outer join would be required. Currently, this is not supported by Flink. However, Flink's streaming API is going to be extended... Furthermore, you can build windows on tuple-time rather than operator/system time. For this case, you can avoid empty windows. It really depends on your use case and the semantics you need...

Comment: I think if two data that should be joined together can't be in the current window within trigger time. They will miss each other. And thank you for your suggestions, I will follow them to do some testing.